# I get the error message @escaping attribute only applies to function types, even though it worked previously

Tags: swift, api

I am currently trying to make an app that tracks prices of crypto. While making an API caller I ran into the issue that it won't let me use escaping even when it previously worked. I am not sure if it is because an update to Xcode or not. Currently on version 12.5.1. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
final class APICall{
    static let instance = APICall()
    
    private struct defaults{
        static let apiKey = ""
        static let assets = ""
    }
    
    private init(){
        
    }
    
    public func getCryptoValues(completion: @escaping Result<[String], Error>) -> Void{
        guard let apiUrl = URL(string: defaults.assets + "?apikey=" + defaults.apiKey)
        else{return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiUrl){ data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            do{
                let cryptos = try JSONDecoder().decode([CryptoCoin].self, from: data)
                completion(.success(cryptos))
            }
            catch{
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There are at least three issues: 1) a typo `.succes` must be `.success` and 2) the *good* type in `Result` doesn't match the decoded type (unless `CryptoCoin` is a type alias of `String`) and 3) there must be an open parentheses before `Result<` and a closing parentheses after `Void`. The latter is the main issue.

Comment: thank you for the feedback didn't even notice the typo don't have the error anymore. and the CryptoCoin is a type alias of String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@vadian* mentioned above, the reason for this issue is that your `completion` parameter should be a `function` to have `@escaping` attribute in front of it.

A `function` that takes the form `(Input) -> Output`

and for this case it should be `completion: @escaping (Input) -> Output`

The issue should go away if you change function signature from

```
public func getCryptoValues(completion: @escaping Result<[String], Error>) -> Void{
```

to

```
public func getCryptoValues(completion: @escaping (Result<[String], Error>) -> Void) {
```